# How to Enumerate of all simple connected labeled graphs with prescribed degree sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, algebraic-graph-theory

For v=4 vertices, there must be 7 possible graphic sequence (3,3,3,3)(3,3,2,2)(3,2,2,1)(3,1,1,1)(2,2,2,2)(2,2,1,1)(1,1,1,1).
From (3,3,3,3), one simple graph(complete) can be found.
From(3,3,2,2), 6 simple connected graphs are possible,From (2,2,1,1), 12 simple connected graphs are possible.

Then how can I determine all simple connected labeled graphs for degree sequence $d_{i}= d_{1},d_{2},...,d_{n} \forall i=1,n $.
Is there any formula or equation exist for the same?

Comment: isn't this a dup of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732303/degree-sequence-of-connected-graphs