# How to prove from a degree sequence that every realization of the graph is connected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For example, how to prove that every realization of a graph of this degree sequence $\left(2,2,2,2,4,4,4,6\right)$ is connected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The verb is "prove", not "proof". "Proof" is a noun. (Unless the graph has yeast in it.)

Answer (score 2):

The last vertex is connected to all but one. The remaining vertex has degree two or four, so it is connected to some other vertex. This completes the proof.

As for other examples, looking at minimal and maximal degrees is a good idea. Thinking about the number of vertices and the number of edges is also important. For example, here the handshaking lemma gives that there are thirteen edges.

If you want further information, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732428/1096797) is an answer with extensive information.

Comment: It's false that there is no strategy. It's true that trying to develop a general method would be overkill for this problem and probably beyond the level of an intro graph theory class.

Comment: Thanks for the push!